# Testing Nested Database Dependencies using MOQ in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing a few unit tests using MOQ in C# for a functionality that was recently developed. It uses some internal classes as well as methods which talks to database and get some values based upon the parameter passed to them e.g.

> if I pass AUD then the database is returning Australia - this code uses some internal static classes which are nested somewhere inside the code therefore I am unable to pass their dependency

Here is the sample code

```
    internal static class ParseReportHelper 
    {  
        private static readonly ICountryRepository CountryRepository; 
        static ParseReportHelper() { 
             CountryRepository = DependencyFactory.Resolve<ICountryRepository>(); 
          }
    }
```

I don't have any idea how should I test this section of code since it has a dependency upon the database as I am missing something or unable to understand. What should be the correct way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe consider to wrap that dependencies in separate service layer?
In that case, you could mock this layer instead of blackboxed code from outside?

Comment: Please show us excerpts from the code. For instance how does this static DB class create the connection? Where is it getting the connection string from?

Comment: Here are the excerpts:

 internal static class ParseReportHelper
    {
        private static readonly ICountryRepository CountryRepository;

        static ParseReportHelper()
        {
            CountryRepository = DependencyFactory.Resolve<ICountryRepository>();
        }
}

Comment: What is the type of `DependencyFactory`? Is it something custom or does it come from a DI framework? Please show us how `ICountryRepository` is being registered in the `DependencyFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

Static dependencies usually cannot be mocked for unit testing. Your options are:

- Use a mocking framework that can do this (those usually cost money).
- Refactor the code such that the DB dependency is injected and can be mocked.
- Write an integration test which connects to a real DB, or a SQLite DB, or an in-memory DB. In case the connection string is part of that static dependency you could try to change it during the test setup using reflection or by making the connection string configurable from the outside.
- Don't test that part of the code.

Comment: Here are the excerpts:
internal static class ParseReportHelper
{
       private static readonly ICountryRepository CountryRepository;
       static ParseReportHelper()
        {
            CountryRepository = DependencyFactory.Resolve<ICountryRepository>();
        }
}

Comment: Put this in the question for better readability pls. It looks like dependency injection is actually being used there, only in an unusual way. Somewhere during startup the `ICountryRepository` is being registered in the `DependencyFactory`. Your tests could do the same.